# Spring-batch split/fork step in job

Tags: java, spring

In my project, i want split/fork step. 
I'm using spring-batch with Java 6.

Is it possible with spring batch have a tree of step ?
[Here an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7IPl.png)

I'm trying to use partioning with master of master of master but it's not possible.

```
<batch:step id="affr" next="banni" parent="parentStep" >
        <batch:partition step="affrSlave" partitioner="stepPartitioner" >
            <batch:handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="affrSlave" next="banni" parent="parentStep" >
        <batch:partition step="banniSlave" partitioner="stepPartitioner" >
            <batch:handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="banniSlave" next="banni" parent="parentStep">
        <batch:partition step="banni" partitioner="stepPartitioner" >
            <batch:handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="banni" parent="parentStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="stepBanni" />
    </batch:step>
```

Error is :
    `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The element [banniSlave] is unreachable`

I think spring-batch is limited. In spring-batch, one step have one next's step.

`- Step1 -
 |         |
Step2    Step2             This is possible with master and slave.
 |         |
  - Step3 -`

`- Step1 -
 |         |
Step2    Step2

 |         |
Step3    Step3             Is this possible ? If yes, how ?
 |         |
  - Step4 -`

Thanks for your help.

Here my code :

```
    <bean id="stepFold" class="com.batch.hubmass.step.Fold" />
<bean id="stepLoti" class="com.batch.hubmass.step.Loti" />
<bean id="stepAffr" class="com.batch.hubmass.step.Affr" />
<bean id="stepBanni" class="com.batch.hubmass.step.Banni" />

<!-- Decider -->
<bean id="affrDecider" class="com.batch.hubmass.decider.AffrDecider"/>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
<bean id="stepPartitioner" class="com.batch.hubmass.StepPartitioner" />

<!-- 6) FINALLY OUR JOB DEFINITION. -->

<!-- Step Parent -->
<batch:job id="parentJob" abstract="true">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobExecutionListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

<batch:step id="parentStep" abstract="true">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="stepExecutionListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:step>

<!-- SimpleJob -->
<batch:job id="simpleJob" parent="parentJob">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="helloTask" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step2" next="step3">
        <batch:tasklet ref="timeTask" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step3">
        <batch:tasklet ref="timeTask" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- BddJob -->
<batch:job id="bddJob" parent="parentJob">
    <batch:step id="stepDbb1" next="stepDbb2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="bddTask" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="stepDbb2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="helloTask" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- HubMass Production -->
<batch:job id="production" parent="parentJob">
    <batch:step id="fold" next="loti" parent="parentStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="stepFold" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="loti" next="decisAffr" parent="parentStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="stepLoti" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:decision id="decisAffr" decider="affrDecider">
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="affr"/>
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="banni"/>
        <batch:fail on="*"/>
    </batch:decision>

    <batch:step id="affr" next="banni" parent="parentStep" >
        <batch:partition step="affrSlave" partitioner="stepPartitioner" >
            <batch:handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="affrSlave" next="banni" parent="parentStep" >
        <batch:partition step="banniSlave" partitioner="stepPartitioner" >
            <batch:handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="banniSlave" next="banni" parent="parentStep">
        <batch:partition step="banni" partitioner="stepPartitioner" >
            <batch:handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>


    <batch:step id="banni" parent="parentStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="stepBanni" />
    </batch:step>

</batch:job>
```